# Google places api PopularTimes on java

Tags: java, google-places-api, google-places

I'm working on a project for college, and i couldn't find the documentation for the "Popular times" section on google maps. I've read online about some people using thrid-party python scripts that read the google search, but as my backend is currently in Java. Is there any official, or even unnoficial way to get this information in Java (without running this python scripts in Java Runtime)?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you are still searching for an answer to your questions, please try this one
[google-populartimes-java](https://github.com/johanneshiry/google-populartimes-java)

It's using the same library you mentioned by in Java